# Why Exception can't be handled

Tags: haskell

I have the following code:

```
handledIO :: Int -> IO Int
handledIO x = handle (printException x) $ return $ [1, 2, 3] !! x

printException :: Int -> SomeException -> IO Int
printException x (SomeException e) = do
  print ("Exception", x, e)
  throw e
```

When I type `handledIO 8` in ghci, I expect to see `("Exception", 8, "*** Exception: Prelude.!!: index too large")` will be printed, but actually only the exception is printed. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is a bit subtle and has to do with Haskell's laziness.

Let's use this version of your example that has the same problem:

```
handledIO :: Int -> IO Int
handledIO x = handle (printException x) $ return undefined
```

The problem is that `handle` only catches exceptions thrown when the `IO` action passed as argument is running. The action `return undefined` completes *successfully* because the `undefined` is never scrutinized from *inside* the action. But when other `IO` actions try to actually inspect the returned value—like, for example, trying to print it to the console—they encounter a nasty surprise.

One solution to this "lazy exception-throwing result value in `IO`" problem is to use the [`evaluate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:evaluate) function from `Control.Exception` instead of `return`. `evaluate` takes care to reduce the argument to WHNF before the `IO` action returns, so it trips the exception:

```
handledIO :: Int -> IO Int
handledIO x = handle (printException x) $ evaluate $ undefined
```

Now it works:

```
*Main> handledIO 10
("Exception",10,Prelude.undefined
```

---

Also, you are using `throw` inside an `IO` action. When inside `IO` actions, [`throwIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:throwIO) is preferable to `throw`.

Comment: HI @danidiaz, Thanks for your answer. I wonder if there is a function that `evaluate` before `handle` it? like `handle' handler io = handle handler $ io >>= evaluate`. Such that I don't need to think whether the exception can be handled or not, because `handle'` will always handle the exception regardless it's WHNF or not.

Comment: @LeoZhang I don't know of such a function, but your definition seems good.